# Как преобразовать изображение с камеры opencv в JPG, а полученный результат в байтовый массив?

Tags: c++, opencv

Мне нужно покадрово преобразовывать видеопоток, полученный с видеокамеры с помощью Opencv в формат jpg, а полученный результат в обычный байтовый массив (массив чаров).

Я нашел как преобразовать кадр в jpg, но не до конца понял как этим пользоваться. Нужно ли обрабно декодировать из мат или нет, чтоб получить jprg или это лишний шаг. Но я не могу понять, как полученный результат преобразовать в байтовый массив. Как я понял, CvMat привести к массиву чаров нельзя. А IplImage можно с помощью imageData. Сработает ли просто получившийся frame привести в массиву чаров и получу ли я в таком случае после всех этих преобразований массив байт, который содержит кадр в jpg формате?

```
int main()
{

    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);


    IplImage* frame= nullptr;

    cvNamedWindow("capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
         frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
         auto temp = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", frame);
         delete frame;
         frame = cvDecodeImage(temp, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
         delete temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp->data.ptr`  - указатель на буфер, который содержит JPEG-данные в виде одной строки формата `8UC1`.

Размер этих данных можно узнать из `temp->width`

[Здесь](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) пара слов описания

> Note: cvEncodeImage returns single-row matrix of type CV_8UC1 that
>   contains encoded image as array of bytes.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало